# My custom minion is executing twice when called from Postman

Tags: sitecore-commerce, minion

I have a custom minion that reads orders and create an excel file with order details. I have configured this minion to run once in 24 hours and it is working perfectly.
But sometimes we need to run it explicitly. We are using postman for it and executing it with "RunMinion" api call. With postman my minion is executing twice.

does anybody faced same issue or can suggest something to look into?

Comment: can you check if you have declared 2 times your minion in the json files?

Comment: Yes already checked that. It is only in minions json file for one environment.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we try to execute a minion from authoring commerce engine role and that minion is defined for minions environment. During execution of request authoring role has to load the minions environment. Environment loading process starts execution of all minions in that environment. Once the environment is loaded authoring role than executes the minion request that was initially triggered.

The solution will be that always run minion from the commerce engine role that is configured to use the minions environment.